# How Do I Programmatically Better Organize Custom Post Type Menus?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu, sub-menu

A project I inherited had a dozen custom post types. Trouble is, they all come off the admin menu sidebar separately. It's not very tidy. Is there a plugin where I can make these subitems of a parent menu, or is there a way, programmatically, I can edit my theme's functions.php to make it make these as submenus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the function  to register a new custom post type can you set this CPT as Submenu to a exist menu item. Use the param `show_in_menu`

A example:

```
register_post_type( 
    'issue', 
    apply_filters( 'wpit_register_issue_post_type', 
        array(
            'labels'          => $issue_labels,
            'rewrite'         => $issue_rewrite,
            'supports'        => $issue_supports,
            'taxonomies'      => $issue_taxonomies,
            'menu_position'   => 5,
            'public'          => TRUE,
            'show_ui'         => TRUE,
            'show_in_menu'    => 'edit.php',
            'can_export'      => TRUE,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'query_var'       => TRUE
        )
    ) 
);
```

You find the string for the items on mouse over, like `upload.php`on the item *Media*.

Comment: I used this handy generator to create a [Custom Post Type](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/), and then I installed the free Admin Menu Editor plugin and created a custom menu called "Management" with slug/hook as "mgmt". Next, all I had to do in my auto-generated custom post type code was add the line `'show_in_menu' => 'mgmt',` and sure enough -- she works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome. For each job give it an generator ;)

Comment: Yeah, I can't always trust generators to be on the web, so I need to just build my own PHP script that replicates this. Plus, it's pretty easy to use the `add_menu_page()` function to create the "Management" menu instead of using the Admin Menu Editor.